# Delphi: How to get the positions of scrollbars of TImgView32 control?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar

I use Graphics32 library and put TImgView32 control on a form. In a code I want to get the position of a vertical scroll bar, but cannot find any properties for that.

How to get the position of a vertical scrollbar of TImgView32 control?

Comment: Apparently the [control](https://graphics32.github.io/Docs/Units/GR32_Image/Classes/TImgView32/_Body.htm) uses an [arbitrator](https://graphics32.github.io/Docs/Units/GR32_Image/Classes/TCustomImgView32/Properties/ScrollBars.htm) to reflect the [properties](https://graphics32.github.io/Docs/Units/GR32_Image/Classes/TIVScrollProperties/_Body.htm) of the [actual scrollbars](https://graphics32.github.io/Docs/Units/GR32_RangeBars/Classes/TCustomRangeBar/_Body.htm) that lives elsewhere. Indeed the property set seem to be limited to cosmetics only. Strange...

Comment: Can't you just access the [range bar](https://graphics32.github.io/Docs/Units/GR32_RangeBars/Classes/TCustomRangeBar/_Body.htm) directly? It has a "position" property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TImgView32` is a `TCustomControl` descendant, which means it has its own `HWND`. So, assuming that window is using a standard Win32-provided scrollbar, try the Win32 API [`GetScrollInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollinfo) function.

```pascal
uses
  Windows;

var
  si: TScrollInfo;
begin
  si.cbSize := sizeof(si);
  si.fMask := SIF_POS;
  if GetScrollInfo(ImgView1.Handle, SB_VERT, si) then
  begin
    // use si.nPos as needed...
  end;
end;
```